# Consequences of this matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have an equation of the form:

$$A(s,t)x = b(s)$$

where $A$ is a real matrix, $x, b$ vectors and $s, t$ scalar parameters.

While generally speaking, if $A$ is singular, the equation generically has no solution, for my specific $A$ and $b$ I observe that 
$$\det(A(s,t))=0 \quad \Rightarrow\quad \exists x \ |\ A(s,t)x=b(s)$$
or, in other words, whenever $(s,t)$ makes $A$  singular, there always exists a solution $x$ to the equation. (Of course when $A$ is not singular there is also a solution: $x=A^{-1}b$.)

The question is, how to characterize the relationship between $A$ and $b$? $b$ is always in the image of $A$, but can I write mathematically in a more explicit way?

Comment: the statement *"there always exists a solution x to the equation"* should be "not always exists a solution x to the equation"

Comment: @janmarqz No! That's precisely the point: for my $A$ and $b$ there is always a solution, while I would expect _almost never_ a solution. So there must be a relationship between $A$ and $b$; question is, which one? (edited to clarify)

Comment: Ok, for $b\neq0$ it is required that $b$ is in the image of $A$ viewed as a map $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$, and in other words $b$ be a linear combination of the columns of $A$, for having always a  solution $x$

Comment: Your notation suggests that, strictly speaking, $A$ is not a matrix, but a function whose value is a matrix, and $b$ is a function whose value is a vector.

Comment: @Acccumulation That's right. $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$. Without further information, I don't think we can say more than what janmarqz wrote...

Comment: Not a very informative title...